# Pre-existing add-ons do not work after starting from a Selenium custom profile

Tags: selenium, firefox

I have a code in C # with very simple Selenium. It is just controlling a VPN extension and navigating to X Page.

The question is that after Selenium starts with the Firefox Custom Profile, the Extensions that the Profile has installed disappear, so it does not allow me to control VPN Extensions.

On My Machine Works Correctly The Problem Is When Executing It On Another Machine.

```
FirefoxProfile profile1 = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\6r8313wg.1");
        FirefoxOptions options1 = new FirefoxOptions();
        options1.Profile = profile1;                
        FirefoxDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver(options1);
        driver1.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        do
        {

            driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("moz-extension://3667138c-f19d-49a2-8ffe-278b50c1e52c//popup.html");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            IWebElement VPN15 = driver1.FindElement(By.ClassName("server-item__server"));
            VPN15.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
            Thread.Sleep(70000);
         } while (!i.Checked);
           driver1.Quit();
```

Comment: selenium remove all addons before starting it. please make sure your profile has the addons

Comment: If you have all the add-ons and it is the profile that I want to open, it disappears after the browser is started. If I go to Settings, there are the add-ons if the deactivated and active appear.